# Create class properties with the help of a macro

Tags: c++, qt, macros, properties

I need to create some mechanism which will allow me to declare class properties (ie: member variables) which can be accessed via their name also beside of the usual class member access. Qt has solved this problem with the very handy `Q_PROPERTY` macro which on the other end is digested by moc. I do not have the luxury of this two step compilation and the closest I could get is this:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
SomeClass() : bla(9), v(9.4) {}
virtual ~SomeClass(){}

int bla;
double v;

BEGIN_ATTRIBUTES(SomeClass)
    ATTRIBUTE(int, bla)
    ATTRIBUTE(double, v)
END_ATTRIBUTES()
};
```

where there are the obvious macros that hide an ugly mechanism to store some data about the class member which is fed into a horrible templated code monster, and this works, but this has the disadvantage that you need to firstly declare the class attributes and then you have a separate section where you actually specify the class member as being an attribute.

I'd more like some code like:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
SomeClass() : bla(9), v(9.4) {}
virtual ~SomeClass(){}

ATTRIBUTE(int, bla);
ATTRIBUTE(double, v);
};
```

But regardless of how hard I try, I just cannot get close to this one lined solution. If anyone has ever implemented something like this I'd be grateful for a few hints.

Comment: Why is it worse to use Q_PROPERTY than to reimplement it?

Answer (score 1):

First let me just note that properties are not idiomatic C++ and the language resists your attempts to use them.

That said, although your question isn't clear did you try something like:

```
#define ATTRIBUTE(type, name) \
type name##_; \
const type& get_##name() const { return name##_; } \
void set_##name(const type& v) { name##_ = v; }

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass() : bla_(9), v_(9.4) {}
    virtual ~SomeClass(){}

    ATTRIBUTE(int, bla);
    ATTRIBUTE(double, v);
};
```

Comment: yes, that was my first attempt (well not exactly but something similar anyway) but I encountered a problem when I tried to implement the access by name. Such as `setAttribute("v", 10.45);` or `double x = attribute("v");`

Comment: @fritzone Can you elaborate on the real problem you're trying to solve? It sounds like you're trying to write code for a different language in C++. C++ isn't dynamic in a way that easily lets you do that.

Comment: I have created a serialization mechanism using the syntax in the question, with the two sequenced attribute identification (first is the normal declaration of the variable and the second is the identification of the attribute, where the macro expands to a function doing all kind of ugly stuff (it is at https://github.com/fritzone/cppserializer  - apologies for advertising own project)) but I sort of don't like this very expanded attribute definition and I'm trying to find out if I can shorten it somehow.